# use a parameter from typescript in template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following a computed property to check wether a user is more active of on social media or on social professional network

```
mediaOrSocial() {
  if (this.socialMedia) {
    const postLikes = this.socialMedia.postLikes;
    return postLikes === 30 || this.postLikes !== 30;
  } else if (this.socialPro) {
    const postLikes = this.socialPro.postLikes;
    return postLikes === 30 || this.postLikes !== 30;
  }
},
```

my question is can I borrow the variable postLikes in template to make a condition on string interporlation in template {{ }} ?

`exp {{ postLikes > 100 ? 'influencer' : 'not enough visibility' }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean postLikes variable that you are defining in the mediaOrSocial() function (not the this.postLikes variable) then no - you can't use it in the template. But you can create another computed property which will return the correct value.

```
numberOfPostLikesForSpecificPlatform() {
  if (this.socialMedia) {
    return this.socialMedia.postLikes;
  } else if (this.socialPro) {
    return this.socialPro.postLikes;
  }
  return null
}
```

then in the template:

```
{{ numberOfPostLikesForSpecificPlatform > 100 ? 'influencer' : 'not enough visibility' }}
```

Remember also to always return some value in the computed property:

```
mediaOrSocial() {
  if (this.socialMedia) {
    const postLikes = this.socialMedia.postLikes;
    return postLikes === 30 || this.postLikes !== 30;
  } else if (this.socialPro) {
    const postLikes = this.socialPro.postLikes;
    return postLikes === 30 || this.postLikes !== 30;
  }
  // or some other value
  return false
},
```

Comment: `(If you mean postLikes variable that you are defining in the mediaOrSocial() function (not the this.postLikes variable) then no - you can't use it in the template.)` can you explain what is the difference if already the variable defined in the computed is receiving **this.postLikes** ??

Comment: Every variable defined inside a method, computed property or hook is accessible only within those functions, if you define a variable inside the data() function you can access it in a template and the previously mentioned functions. I assumed that postLikes and this.postLikes are not the same because otherwise why not use only this.postLikes inside mediaOrSocial() function? I could help more I you provide the whole code of the Vue component because right now I making a lot of assumptions.

Comment: ok clear, I'm just confused with what you are referring to by **hook** ?

Comment: other question `if you define a variable inside the data() function you can access it in a template and the previously mentioned functions.` I can use data & also **props** within template right ?

Comment: @danysh about hooks - I meant [lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html), sorry for that mental shortcut. Regarding the second question - yes, you can use props within a template.